# Radiobutton OnCheckedChanged loses its value when dropdownlist OnSelectedIndexChanged called in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a 2 radiobutton on my webpage, they both have OnCheckedChanged event lik this

```
 protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gender = "Male";
        }

    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gender = "Female";
    }
```

and i also have a dropdownlist which has OnSelectedIndexChanged event which populate an other dropdwonlist.

```
protected void Depid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         string id = Depiddrop.SelectedValue.ToString();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select StaffID, Name from Staff where Depid='" + id + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

             con.Open();
            empiddrop.DataSource = dt;
            empiddrop.DataTextField = "Name";
            empiddrop.DataValueField = "StaffID";
             empiddrop.DataBind();

        }
```

...the problem is that gender variable lose their value after postback (selectingitem from asp.net dropdownlist control). i also set the radiobutton property enableviewstate="true" but its not solving the problem.
..please help...and thanks

Answer (score 0):

declare gender as static global variable

use something like

```
static string gender="";
```

use this as global variable